# How to diagnose slow PiVPN speeds?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, ipv6, wireguard

I'm using an Oracle free tier arm VPS on Ubuntu 22.04 as a VPN server. I have set it up with PiVPN + Pihole. The VPS has ipv6 and ipv4 connectivity. When I connect to the VPN (wireguard protocol) and run a speed test on fast.com, I only get around 40 Mbps, while my ISP provides 80 Mbps. If I run the speed test without connecting to the VPN I get around 78 Mbps. How can I diagnose and fix this issue? I am a beginner so detailed instructions would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of network speed is provided to the VPS? Are you sure the VPS itself is allowed to go above 40 Mbps?

Comment: Does your ISP provide 80 Mbps download, upload or overall? Is the bandwidth symmetrical? Note that both (network download and client upload) are used by VPN  servers.

Comment: My upload and download is symmetrical. The VPS has a 4Gbps connection and I verified this by running the speedtest cli on the server.